# DRY using handlebars and twitter bootstrap in Meteor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, handlebars.js

I am building my first web application with twitter bootstrap and I am liking it, but I am running into a problem of repeating myself.

I am building a navigation bar, and I want the UI to reflect which tab is active based on the url. I am using backbone to route the urls. The only problem is that I have to manually code a bunch of different variables to be "active" or "" based on the url so that the tabs will reflect the appropriate state.

```
<template name="navbar">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="{{home}}">
            <a href="/home/">Home</a></li>

        <li class="{{1999s10}}{{1965malibu}}{{1960hearse}}{{1966gto}}{{1971blazer}} dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Cars<b class="caret"></b></a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="{{1999s10}}"><a href="/cars/1999s10">1999 Electric S-10</a></li>
                <li class="{{1965malibu}}"><a href="/cars/1965malibu">1965 Malibu</a></li>
                <li class="{{1960hearse}}"><a href="/cars/1960hearse">1960 Hearse</a></li>
                <li class="{{1966gto}}"><a href="/cars/1966gto">1966 GTO</a></li>
                <li class="{{1971blazer}}"><a href="/cars/1971blazer">1971 Bazer</a></li>
                <!-- <li class="divider"></li> -->
            </ul>
        </li>  
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, right now, I have a bunch of variables for indicating what tabs are active. I have started to implement the following code, but Its so inelegant that I have stopped and want to use a better method.

```
Template.navbar.home = function () {
    return Session.equals("active", "home") ? "active" : '';
};

// a bunch more of these for every route

var TodosRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "home/": "home",
            // more routes
    },
    home: function () {
        Session.set("active", "home");
    },
    // more functions for capturing the routes and setting the session variable "active"
});

Router = new TodosRouter;

Meteor.startup(function () {
    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
});
```

Using this method: 
(1) has the issue of variables that start with numbers (my bad)
(2) requires me to route every url to change the Session "active" variable accordingly
(3) requires me to make a template handler for every button/url in the navigation bar

There has to be a better method for doing this, but I have yet to find it.

To reiterate, I want to find a way of accomplish activating the necessary tabs without breaking the DRY (do not repeat yourself) programming principle.

edit:

What would be really nice is something like this:

```
<li class="{{(url=="/cars/1999s10/")?"active":""}}"><a href="/cars/1999s10">1999 Electric S-10</a></li>
```

That would be a minimal amount of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out something that works:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('TabActive', function (route) {
    var url = Session.get("url");
    var index = $.inArray(route, url);
    return (index != -1) ? "active" : "";
});


var TodosRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "*url": "main"
    },
    main: function (url) {
        Session.set("url", url.split('/'))
    }
});
```

and in the html, the " vs ' is crucial!

```
<li class='{{TabActive "home"}}'>
```

this works, but my only concern is the using the router for other urls later...

Answer (score 6):

You could try creating a global Handlebars helper that takes the route name as a parameter and return the correct classname:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Handlebars.registerHelper('TabClassName', function (route) {
        return Session.equals("active", route) ? "active" : "";
    });
}
```

Then in your template, call the helper like this:

```
<li class="{{TabClassName 'home'}}">
```

Comment: Here is the updated code for 0.8.2, using Spacebars and iron-router:

`UI.registerHelper('TabClassName', function (route) {
    if (Router.current()) {
        return Router.current().route.name === route ? "active" : "";
}
});`

Comment: Iron router changed how you access the route's name. You now need to call `Router.current().route.getName()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an static app state class to take care of the current state of my app.

It uses the `Session` to store the current state.

In a handlebars helper I test for the correct state

(coffeescript)

```cs
Template.foo.helpers
  is_active: ->
    appState.isState appState.FOO
```

and in the template I'll use it to style my links

```html
{{#if is_active}}
  <a href="/bar" class="active">/bar</a>
{{else}}
  <a href="/bar">/bar</a>
{{/if}}
```

The appstate object is quite simple

```cs
appState =
  FOO : "foo"
  BAR: "bar"

  setState: (state) ->
    Session.set(SESSION_STATE, state)

  getState: ->
    Session.get(SESSION_STATE)

  isState: (state) ->
    @getState() is state
```

If anywhere in my app the appstate is changed, the reactive magic will happen ;)

```cs
appState.setState appState.LIST
```

### Update:

Using the `rendered` callback to add an active class to navigation items (untested!)

```cs
Template.foo.rendered = ->
  current = Backbone.history.fragment
  links = this.findAll("ul li a")

  links.forEach((link) ->
    $(link).parent().addClass("active") if link.href is current  
  )
```

Comment: I see what you're doing here, but it still requires a tedious amount of code for managing, say 50 different urls.

Comment: Hm, as you can't use Handlebars the way you did in your edit, I don't see how to do this out of the box with meteor.

As I don't have to manage 50 different URLs my solution is ok for me... I use this for navigation highlighting and view-state-switching with 4 different states. 50 would be another story...

Comment: One more idea: what if you add the highlighting with js/jquery in the `template.rendered` callback? You could do everything you need with normal javascript without the handlebars restrictions.

Comment: Hmm. I dont mean to hassle you, but can you give me an example of how you would do that? I just don't see how this is going to clean up the code much...

Answer (score 0):

As jtblin pointed out you can use a Template helper for this. The code below runs with Meteor > 1.0 and Iron Router > 0.9.4.

Instead of passing a route name to the helper you can pass a regular expression, which makes it more suitable if you have submenus.

```
# file: /client/helpers.coffee

Template.registerHelper 'activeMenuItem', (expression) ->
   reg = new RegExp(expression, 'i')
   if reg.test Router.current().route.getName() then "active" else ""
```

Use the helper in your template like this:

```
<li class="menu {{activeMenuItem 'persons'}}"> … </li>
```

This way you will get "active" back for all routes beginning with persons (eg. personsList, personsAdd, personsEdit, etc.). Therefore it is also a good fit if you have submenus.

Answer (score -1):

I came up with the following quite generic solution:

```
# Store currently selected bootstrap tab so that active state can be restored on reload

$(document).on 'click', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', (e) ->
  Session.set("selected_tab", $(e.target).attr("href").replace("#", ""))

# Helper for determining active state of a tab navigation
Handlebars.registerHelper 'tab', ( options ) ->
  $el = $('<ul />').html( options.fn(this) )

  $selected_tab = $el.find('a[data-toggle="tab"][href=#' + Session.get("selected_tab") + ']')
  $selected_tab = $el.find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').first() if $selected_tab.length == 0

  # Mark navigation item as active
  $selected_tab.parent().addClass("active")

  # Mark content item as active
  $el.find($selected_tab.attr("href")).addClass("in active")

  return $el.html()
```

Usage:

```
{{#tab}}
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><a href="#article_tweet_pane" data-toggle="tab">Tweet</a></li>
  <li><a href="#article_blog_pane" data-toggle="tab">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="#article_newsletter_pane" data-toggle="tab">Newsletter</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="article_tweet_pane" class="tab-pane fade">Tweet</div>
  <div id="article_blog_pane" class="tab-pane fade">Blog</div>
  <div id="article_newsletter_pane" class="tab-pane fade">Newsletter</div>
</div>
{{/tab}}
```